# How do I edit my registration e-mail from OpenCart

Tags: php, css, email, opencart

I'm struggling with this for hours now so I hope some of you can help me. I just want to know how to change the styling of the OpenCart registry email that you get when you register on the webshop. When I search it on google the only thing people say is that I have to go to *catalog/language/YOURLANGUAGE/mail/customer.php* but the only thing I can change there is the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know where the emails are send from in the code, that would be: **catalog\model\account\customer.php**

There you have the function that send emails, you will have a hard time editing if you want to send a html mail for example, but that file is the start you are in need of, afterwards you can work in many different ways to achieve what you want.